# How to show blinking cursor in a readonly Material UI TextField in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have set the TextField to be `readOnly` as I don't want the phone keypad to popup when user taps on it, instead I have a custom keypad for input. Everything works fine except there is no blinking cursor which denotes that the field is editable. The webapp is only intended for mobile browsers.

```
<TextField
    error={globalContext.isInputError}
    value={globalContext.amount}
    multiline={false}
    autoFocus
    placeholder={Math.abs(globalContext.balanceDue).toString()}
    helperText={
        <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.input} display="block">
            {globalContext.inputHelperText}
        </Typography>
    }
    margin="normal"
    InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start" classes={{ positionStart: classes.centerAdornment }}>
                <Typography variant="h6" display="block">
                    ₹
                </Typography>
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
        readOnly: true,
        style: { fontSize: '22px', fontWeight: 'bold' }
    }}
    className={classes.input}
/>
```

How do I display the blinking cursor in TextField?